# How to print texts like this - "kuṇḍalaṁ"?

Tags: android, fonts

In this program I have used statement to print "kuṇḍalaṁ gokule bhrājamanam".Carefully observe that the above print statement contain the letter ṇ ,ḍ, ṁ. When I execute this program these above letters didn't print. These kind of text belongs  to the balaram fonts. I have installed this font but still I am not getting the the output as "kuṇḍalaṁ gokule bhrājamanam" properly. Is there any way I can come out of this problem
     `package com.example.balramfont;

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.graphics.Typeface;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initTypeface();

}

private void initTypeface() {
TextView display;


 Typeface  balramfont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/balram4.ttf");
     display=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    display.setTypeface(balramfont);
    display.setText(" kuṇḍalaṁ gokule bhrājamanam");


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

      } `
```

Comment: Hello new user, Welcome to SO. No one would be able to solve your problem without the code. So please do post here, what you have tried and what you are getting and *what you are not getting*.